# VueJS Zoom in/out performance lags

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a web app which has a lot of tables that get rendered on the page, however I have noticed the performance of the web page reduces drastically the more I add. Especially when i zoom in and out, this causing the page to lag for a few seconds. Is there any way to work around this? I have heard lazy loading is a good method, however that seems like its only for initial loads.

```html
<v-text-subtitle name="moaamlol6" class="blue--text"
            >Mapping of Assessment Against Module Learning Outcomes - Level
            6</v-text-subtitle
          >
          <v-dialog
            v-model="dialogL6"
            fullscreen
            hide-overlay
            transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="red lighten-2"
                dark
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                outlined
              >
                Edit
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title
                  >Mapping of Assessment Against Module Learning Outcomes -
                  Level 6</v-toolbar-title
                >
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-toolbar-items>
                  <v-btn text dark @click="dialogL6 = false"> Cancel </v-btn>
                  <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
                  <v-btn dark text @click="generateL6"> Insert </v-btn>
                </v-toolbar-items>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text style="display: inline-flex">
                <div>
                  <table class="bordered" ref="L6">
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="99">
                        Mapping of Assessment Against Module Learning Outcomes -
                        Level 6
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th rowspan="2">Module Assessment Elements</th>
                      <th colspan="99">Module Learning Outcomes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index">
                        {{ index }}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="y in specMod.length" v-bind:key="y">
                      <td>{{ specMod[y - 1].module_name }}</td>
                      <td
                        class="notclicked"
                        v-for="x in numOfCLO"
                        v-bind:key="x"
                        :id="x + '*' + y"
                        @click="changeClassL6(x, y)"
                      ></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p v-html="courseDataJson[0].mapping_assessment_l6"></p>
                </div>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <p
            v-html="courseDataJson[0].mapping_assessment_l6"
            v-if="dialogL6 == false"
          ></p>
```

I have 4x of these tables, however the performance is fine. But once I add the final table the performance tanks

```html
 <v-text-subtitle name="isfa" class="blue--text"
            >Indicative Schedule for Assessment</v-text-subtitle
          >
          <table class="bordered" ref="indicative">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="99">Indicative Schedule for Assessment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Week</th>
              <td>Level 3</td>
              <td>Level 4</td>
              <td>Level 5</td>
              <td>Level 6</td>
              <td>Level 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>TT</th>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="x in 52" :key="x">
              <th>Week {{ x }}</th>
              <td
                v-for="y in 5"
                :key="y"
                @click="openDialog(x, y)"
                class="clickable"
              >
                <div v-for="data in schedule_dataJson" v-bind:key="data.id">
                  <v-card
                    v-if="data.week == x && data.level == y + 2 && data.courseId == courseDataJson[0].id"
                    class="mt-2 mb-2"
                    color="#F5F5F5"
                  >
                    <v-toolbar :color="data.colour">
                      <v-toolbar-title>
                        <v-icon>{{ data.icon }}</v-icon> {{ data.name }} |
                        {{ data.location }}
                      </v-toolbar-title>
                    </v-toolbar>
                    <v-card-text v-if="data.note != null">
                      {{ data.note }}
                      
                    </v-card-text>
                  </v-card>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            width="500"
            height="1000"
            persistent
            transition="scale-transition"
          >
            <v-card>
              <v-toolbar color="blue">
                <v-toolbar-title>
                  Enter Schedule - Week {{ week }} - Level {{ level + 2 }}
                </v-toolbar-title>
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text
                ><v-select label="Icon" :items="items" v-model="icon">
                  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                    <v-icon>{{ data.item }}</v-icon>
                  </template>
                  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                    <v-icon>{{ data.item }}</v-icon>
                  </template>
                </v-select></v-card-text
              >
              <v-card-text
                ><v-text-field label="Select Name" v-model="name"></v-text-field
              ></v-card-text>
              <v-card-text
                >Select Colour:
                {{ colour }}
                <v-color-picker
                  class="ma-2"
                  dot-size="30"
                  v-model="colour"
                  :swatches="swatches"
                  show-swatches
                  hide-canvas
                  disabled
                  hide-inputs
                ></v-color-picker
              ></v-card-text>
              <v-card-text
                ><v-text-field
                  label="Select Location"
                  v-model="location"
                ></v-text-field
              ></v-card-text>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-textarea auto-grow outlined label="Notes" v-model="note">
                </v-textarea>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card-subtitle
                ><v-btn text color="primary" @click="dialog2 = true"
                  >Existing Events</v-btn
                ></v-card-subtitle
              >
              <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog2"
                transition="slide-y-transition"
                width="500"
                height="1000"
                persistent
              >
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-title class="pink lighten-2">
                    Delete Existing Events
                  </v-card-title>
                  <div v-for="data in schedule_dataJson" v-bind:key="data.test">
                    <v-toolbar
                      :color="data.colour"
                      v-if="data.week == week && data.level == level + 2"
                    >
                      <v-toolbar-title>
                        {{ data.name }} |
                        <v-icon>{{ data.icon }} | {{ data.id }} </v-icon>
                      </v-toolbar-title>
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-toolbar-items>
                        <v-btn icon @click="deleted(data.id)"
                          ><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn
                        >
                      </v-toolbar-items>
                    </v-toolbar>
                  </div>
                  <v-divider></v-divider>
                  <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn @click="dialog2 = false">close</v-btn>
                  </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
              </v-dialog>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn @click="dialog = false" color="primary" text
                  >Cancel</v-btn
                >
                <v-btn @click="insert" color="primary" text>Insert</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
```

Comment: Unfortunately as it stands, this seems a bit broad. Can you post some of your code so that we can review where the performance lag may be occuring?

Comment: I have edited and added the code that causes it

Comment: How much data is in `schedule_dataJson`? Blindly looping over `260 x schedule_dataJson.length` per render hoping it matches some data is wasteful, instead, you should use a computed prop which has the data that then you simply loop though to make the table, i.e one v-for not 3 nested.. Also look into using AJAX with serverside pagination etc, adding 100k elements to the DOM is slow no matter how you structure it

Comment: what do you mean by using 1 for loop to make the table?